# Joining Google Docs table to feature class at ArcGIS Online to use in Operations Dashboard?

Tags: arcgis-online, attribute-joins, google-docs, operations-dashboard

I am using ArcGIS operation Dashboard.

I get the Data Source from excel file that i have published using google docs as a dynamically data source.

I need to [join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/tables/joining-attributes-in-one-table-to-another.htm) the excel table to hosted feature service on Arcgis-Online and give it diffrent colors and diffrent labels by the joined attributes.

For example - Building Layer Joined to money collection table - green buildings already paid, red building didn't paid yet. The color of the layer is changing by the attribute of the table. And when I update the excel table the layer will automatically be updated.

How can I join this table (google docs) to a feature class in AGOL and use it on Operations Dashboard ?

Comment: As per the [tour] there should be only one question per question.

Answer (score 4):

The following is an except from an Esri technical article:

> Relating tables, via relationship classes, may be performed in ArcMap
>   and then published as a service. Related records may then be displayed
>   in pop-up windows in ArcGIS Online.
>
> Depending on how the relationship class is created, users are able to
>   add or update features and have the related data be updated in the
>   pop-up as well.
>
> However, related tables cannot natively be created in ArcGIS Online,
>   and the in-memory joins or relates are not supported in a feature
>   service.
>
> Temporary joins are not visible in ArcGIS Online. Joins from Join
>   Fields persist in ArcGIS Online as the fields are permanently appended
>   to the table.

It appears that you cannot produce a join or relate in AGOL using your web-hosted spreadsheet. You would have to add the google table information to ArcMap and create a relate OR create fields in your hosted layer for the join and then attempt to join in the appropriate data from the table. I would then attempt to markup a join by editing the service definition draft or SSD. I have never done this before, but I am used to editing the SDD and I will warn you that it involves a lot of risk so practice on a COPY.

Alternatively, you can add your data to your google spreadsheet since the feature service data is static, and the spreadsheet data is dynamic, and just visualize the published spreadsheet standalone and you don't even have to worry about a join.

If you don't need to JOIN and just need to ADD the data from google, you can follow this blog post: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/02/21/using-google-docs-in-your-arcgis-online-maps/ 
But I think you already know this... Alternatively, google has it's own mapping app for mapping spreadsheets: http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/spreadsheet3.html

Lastly, you can cut google spreadsheets out of the operation entirely, and just use AGOL since they allow you to manage and edit data as well as track edits.